# Writing the resultset to csv file

Tags: java, arraylist, resultset

I have a method getstaffinfo, which has 3 parameter (var_1, connection, filewriter fw), the var_1 value is read from a text file. So the method will be called as many times based on all the var_1 value passed from text file . approx ( 15000)

```
public static String getstaffid(String var_1, Connection connection,
        FileWriter fw) throws SQLException, Exception
// Create a statement
{
    String record = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    boolean empty = true;
    try {
        rs = stmt
                .executeQuery("select username, firstname, lastname, middlename, street, city, stateorprovince, ziporpostalcode, countryorregion, fax, phone, extension, mobile, pager, title, primaryemail, secondaryemail, officename, description, comments, suspendeddate, userdata, employeeid, createuser, updateuser, createdate, updatedate, employeetype, servicedeskticketnumber, startdate, enddate, manager, businessapprover, technicalapprover, delegate, location, jobcodes, customproperty1, customproperty2, customproperty3, customproperty4, customproperty5, customproperty6, customproperty7, customproperty8, customproperty9, customproperty10 from globalusers where username = '"+ var_1 + "'");
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
        int columns = metaData.getColumnCount();
        ArrayList<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (rs.next()) {
            empty = false;

            //record = rs.getString(1) + " " + rs.getString(2) + " " + rs.getString(3) + " " + rs.getString(4) + " " + rs.getString(5) + " " + rs.getString(6) + " " + rs.getString(7) + " " + rs.getString(8) + " " + rs.getString(9) + " " + rs.getString(10) + " " + rs.getString(11) + " " + rs.getString(12) + " " + rs.getString(13) + " " + rs.getString(14) + " " + rs.getString(15) + " " + rs.getString(16) + " " + rs.getString(17) + " " + rs.getString(18) + " " + rs.getString(19) + " " + rs.getString(20) + " " + rs.getString(21) + " " + rs.getString(22) + " " + rs.getString(23) + " " + rs.getString(24) + " " + rs.getString(25) + " " + rs.getString(26) + " " + rs.getString(27) + " " + rs.getString(28) + " " + rs.getString(29) + " " + rs.getString(30) + " " + rs.getString(31) + " " + rs.getString(32) + " " + rs.getString(33) + " " + rs.getString(34) + " " + rs.getString(35) + " " + rs.getString(36) + " " + rs.getString(37) + " " + rs.getString(38) + " " + rs.getString(39) + " " + rs.getString(40) + " " + rs.getString(41) + " " + rs.getString(42) + " " + rs.getString(43) + " " + rs.getString(44) + " " + rs.getString(45) + " " + rs.getString(46) + " " + rs.getString(47);

            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                String value = rs.getString(i);
                records.add(value);
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < records.size(); j++) {
                 record = records.get(j) + ",";
            }
             fw.append(record);
            }
            /*fw.append(rs.getString(1));
            fw.append(',');
            fw.append(rs.getString(2));
            fw.append(',');
            fw.append(rs.getString(3));
            fw.append('\n'); */

            } finally {
        fw.flush();
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
    }

    return record;
}
```

As you can see, am executing a query for 47 values, which could be null or it can have some value.

Then i iterate through this 47 column, take the value and store it to an array list. Then i iterate the array list and write all the values to the string record with comma seperated value. Which is written to a csv file.

But it does not work fine. Any inputs would be appreciated...

Comment: do you have stack trace ?

Comment: An error in  for (int j = 0; i < records.size(); j++), Should that be j < records.size()

Comment: Hi, it is j<records.size()

Comment: You've got 'i' instead of 'j' in that loop.

Comment: Sorry Pawel, I just edited the code before i posted, it is j in the actual code.

Comment: You need to be more precise - any details on what does it mean "it does not work fine" ?

Answer (score 2):

You may have already solved the problem. Just let you know that I tried to use your code just now and found the issue was here:

```
record = records.get(j) + ",";
```

You should use something like this:

```
record = record  + records.get(j) + ",";
```

Also change `String` to `StringBuffer` will improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write the **exact problem** you face, but there is one for sure: you never write a line break into the file, so all data gets in one line.

```
while (rs.next()) {
... // your code, with the for loops

    fw.append(record); //writing out the line, from your code
    fw.append("\r\n"); //line break -- add this line
} //this is the end of the "while(rs.next())" loop
...
```